# How to make Asterisk answer a Call, and then Play a Audio File?

Tags: configuration, config, asterisk

I need to have an asterisk Instance answer a call from a sip connection, and play an audio message...
I dont know much about asterisk, so some conffile examples would be nice.

I allready messd around a bit but with no result :(

sip.conf:

```
[general]
port = 5060
bindaddr = 0.0.0.0
context = sonstige

register => 6613:noooooooooooooope@hg.eventphone.de/6613

[13]
type=friend
context=meine-telefone
secret=1234
host=dynamic
```

extensions.conf:

```
[sonstige]

[meine-telefone]
exten => 13,1,Answer()
exten => 13,2,Playback(a13msg)
exten => 13,3,Hangup()

[von-voip-provider]
exten => 6613,1,Dial(SIP/13)
```

Comment: What exactly examples you want? you context meine-telefone SHOULD do what you asked if dialled 13.

Comment: Could you provide the asterisk log?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check Peer is registered or not.?
2. Context name in SIP user should be same as context you're writing into extensions.conf.
3. If You're trying with internal SIP phone then

```
[meine-telefone]
exten=>13,1,Answer()
exten=>13,2,Playback(a13msg)
exten=>13,3,Hangup()
```

If you're receiving incoming over trunk then

```
[von-voip-provider]
exten => 6613,1,answer
same=>n,Playback(tt-monkeys)
same=>n,hangup()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think Vivek mishra answer is good. Anyway, if you want the call to go to `exten => 13,1,Answer()` "line" from [von-voip-provider] context, I would change the line `exten => 6613,1,Dial(SIP/13)` to `exten => 6613,1,Goto(meine-telefone,13,1)` That way, the call goes to context "meine-telefone", extension 13, priority 1 right after arriving to von-voip-provider context.

Hope it helped.